# How to use string operations on braid groups in MAGMA

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas, braid-groups

I am currently learning to use the computer algebra program MAGMA. It might be a very basic question but I could not find anything about it.

I am working with elements in braid groups and I want to use basic string operations such as "Subword", "Eliminate", "Substitute" etc on braid group elements. Is that possible?

Whenever I try to apply the command directly, I get the error message:

Runtime error in '...': Bad argument types
Argument types given: GrpBrdElt, GrpBrdElt, ..

I suspect it has to do with the fact that the string operations are defined on SgpFPElt instead of GrpBrdElt. Is there a way to change this type or an alternative way for string operations on words for braid words?

Thank you very much in advance.